# How to read and process JSON with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to take the following JSON and output it to a `<div>` called "#updateArea" using jQuery and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my code, so anything helps.

My JSON:

```
{
    "entry": [
        {
            "heading":"About us",
            "paragraph": "Some Text",
            "paragraph2": "Some Text"
        }
    ]
}
```

My jQuery:

```
function JSON(){
    $.getJSON('about.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data.entry, function(i,entry) {
            var html = '<h1>' + entry.heading + '</h1>';
            html += '<div>' + entry.paragraph + '</div>';
            html += '<div>' + entry.paragraph2 + '</div>';
            $('#updateArea').append(html);
        });
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need to put a slash before the url (i.e. "/about.json")? In any case, you need to change `data` to `data.entry` in the first argument of the `each` function so that it can be passed the array.

Comment: Also, you have a typo in your code, `paragraph` is misspelled as `paragragh`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead:

```
function JSON(){
    $.getJSON('about.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data.entry, function(i, entry) {
            var html = '<h1>' + entry.heading + '</h1>';
            html += '<div>' + entry.paragraph + '</div>';
            html += '<div>' + entry.paragraph2 + '</div>';
            $('#updateArea').append(html);
        });
    });
}
```

You'll need to loop through `data.entry`, instead of just `data`.